# Why can't I beat Hypothermia?

Tags: rimworld

I cannot beat Hypothermia when I begin a new rimworld. Every(!) game I start, even in the dessert, my colonists immediately suffer from Hypothermia.
Group hugging around campfires doesn't work, the hypothermia goes up and up and up. Temperature at this spot is 28°C.

So, what's the trick beating hypothermia early in game, when it doesn't appear random anymore and even kills the settlers standing at a fireplace?

Two of them are wearing Hyperthread winter cloaks, that are supposed to keep them warm and dry
Difficulty is level 2, storyteller is Chillax

[image]

Comment: Just as I posted the question I saw, the Winter cloak sets the lower comfortable temperature to 68°C. I think this may be a bug...? As soon as I remove the cloak, hypothermia stabelizes and even goes down

Comment: If you're asking about a modded game, it helps to include a modlist.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can export it (I am too lazy to type)

Comment: Yep this is definitely some mod hiccup. Hypothermia happens at negative degrees C I believe, depending on your clothes vs outdoors temperature. It can pretty much only happen in temperate or colder biomes. When I did an arctic base in mostly vanilla Rimworld, I had this outpost away from my main base which was very primitive. Basically just some crappy wooden hut and a campfire, some torches maybe. Badly dressed characters survived just fine there, but risked freezing to death when travelling between bases on the main map.

Comment: Be sure to designate the roof area too. Sometimes my paws just leave a place uncovered when I build into a wall.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you are playing some modded version as Winter Cloak is not an item in vanilla Rimworld.

As you say in your comment, it might be a bug.

To prevent hypothermia in vanilla Rimworld either wall up and use a heat source or use proper winter clothing (parkas, tuques)

Comment: It seems one mod has messed up the Material Effect Multiplier, where it should be e.g. at 20 or 26 perced, it is at 200%, which then increased the Insulation - Cold value. Thanks :)

Comment: @Alexander probably worth informing the mod's creators / maintainers!